# Where does jetAudio store bookmarks?

Tags: organizer-software

I use [jetAudio](http://www.jetaudio.com/). I want to move my video files and I really want to keep my jetAudio bookmarks too.

Does anyone know where jetAudio keeps its bookmarks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, for those who are interested, the storing place is here: `C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Roaming\COWON\jetAudio`